# Куки хранятся бесконечно

Tags: firefox, cookie

Кука PHPSESSID должна удалятся после окончания сессии (т.е. при закрытии бразуера). В настройках firefox стоит сохранять куки до истечения срока их действия. Нашел эту куку, в FF написано что её время жизни до конца сессии. Закрываю и опять открываю FF и всё таже кука висит. В чём проблема? подскажите пожалуйста. Скрипт для проверки использую свой, в нём только start_session(); И кстати в Google  Chrome таже история.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это известная багофича в FF, вот описание проблемы в их bug tracker'е: [(eternalsession) Session restore can result in excessive session cookie lifespan](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=530594).

Проблема состоит в session restore: при рестарте браузера он восстанавливает сессию таким образом, что бразуер как бы и не закрывался. Соответственно, и cookies сохраняются, так как сессия вроде бы и не прекращалась.

Comment: а что на счет Google Chrome? Увидели что в ФФ баг такой, решили и себе реализовать:)?

Comment: @Jeremen1: Думаю, у Chrome та же проблема. Кстатуи, если хотите, можете зарегистрироваться на bugzilla.mozilla.org и откомментировать.